# How can we see Closed User Stories in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile

I want data of all stories closed between October 2021 to March 2022.
How can i do that.
Can you please help?

Comment: Post what you have tried. There should be a query option to use with required filters in the UI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following query:
[image]